# How to Calculate Cost of Goods Sold

Tags: postgresql, accounting

I have an inventory table. Inventory table SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE INVENTORY
(
    INVENTORY_ID             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    INVENTORY_DATE           date NOT NULL,
    ITEM_NAME                text NOT NULL,
    PURCHASED_QUANTITY       INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    SOLD_QUANTITY            INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    AMOUNT                   MONEY NOT NULL,
    TOTAL                    MONEY NOT NULL       
);

INSERT INTO INVENTORY(INVENTORY_DATE, ITEM_NAME, PURCHASED_QUANTITY, SOLD_QUANTITY, AMOUNT, TOTAL)
SELECT '1/1/2014'::date, 'ITEM-001', 10, NULL, 100, 1000 UNION ALL
SELECT '1/2/2014'::date, 'ITEM-001', NULL, 2, 200, 400 UNION ALL
SELECT '1/3/2014'::date, 'ITEM-001', 20, NULL, 110, 2200 UNION ALL
SELECT '1/4/2014'::date, 'ITEM-001', NULL, 4, 200, 800 UNION ALL
SELECT '1/5/2014'::date, 'ITEM-001', 20, NULL, 80, 1600;
```

Table

```
SELECT * FROM INVENTORY;

INVENTORY_DATE    ITEM_NAME    PURCHASED_QUANTITY    SOLD QUANTITY     AMOUNT    TOTAL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1/2014          ITEM-001     10                                      $100      $1000
1/2/2014          ITEM-001                           2                 $200      $400
1/3/2014          ITEM-001     20                                      $110      $2200
1/4/2014          ITEM-001                           4                 $200      $800
1/5/2014          ITEM-001     20                                      $80       $1600
```

I am trying to create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_FIFO_COGS(ITEM_NAME TEXT, QUANTITY INTEGER)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
$$
BEGIN

END
$$
LANGUAGE "PLPGSQL";
```

So that, I could :

```
SELECT * FROM GET_FIFO_COGS('ITEM-001', 4) --> $400
--Remaining 4. Each for $100.

SELECT * FROM GET_FIFO_COGS('ITEM-001', 12) --> $1280
--4 for $100, 8 for 110.

SELECT * FROM GET_FIFO_COGS('ITEM-001', 34) --> $3400
--4 for $100, 20 for $110, 10 for $80.
```

I can improve this question if pointed into the right direction. I am learning SQL, this one is giving me troubles and I am unable to solve this problem because I find it quite tricky for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0a68d/1)

The approach in this solution is to expand each row with `n` items to `n` rows with a single item using `generate_series`. Then building two separate sets for `purchased` and `sold`. Each set's rows are numbered in the `inventory_id` order so it is possible to eliminate the `purchased` items that have already been `sold`. Then `order by` the `inventory_id` and `limit` to the quantity.

```
create or replace function get_fifo_cogs(_item_name text, _quantity int)
returns money as $$
    with inventory as (
        select 
            inventory_id, inventory_date,
            generate_series(1, greatest(purchased_quantity, sold_quantity)),
            amount,
            purchased_quantity is not null as purchased
        from inventory
        where item_name = _item_name
    ), purchased as (
        select *, row_number() over(order by inventory_id) as rn
        from inventory
        where purchased
    ), sold as (
        select *, row_number() over(order by inventory_id) as rn
        from inventory
        where not purchased
    )
    select sum(amount) as cogs
    from (
        select amount
        from purchased
        where not exists (
            select 1
            from sold
            where rn = purchased.rn
        )
        order by inventory_id
        limit _quantity
    ) s;
$$ language sql;
```

Use it as

```
select cogs from get_fifo_cogs('ITEM-001', 4) gfc(cogs);
  cogs   
---------
 $400.00
(1 row)

select cogs from get_fifo_cogs('ITEM-001', 12) gfc(cogs);
   cogs    
-----------
 $1,280.00
(1 row)

select cogs from get_fifo_cogs('ITEM-001', 34) gfc(cogs);
   cogs    
-----------
 $3,400.00
```

Or just

```
select get_fifo_cogs('ITEM-001', 4) as cogs;
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly. If I order by inventory in descending order, would I get the LIFO value?

Comment: @Nancy Didn't analyze it, but I guess yes.

Comment: Thank you. I will try from hereon. +(1) for nicely explaining the code.

Comment: One new thing I noticed here, what is purpose of gfc in the above code? Upon searching, I did not find anything like that in the documentation. :)

Comment: @Nancy It is just an alias for the function so it is possible to name the returned column. Or just use the second syntax.

Comment: Colodoaldo, I got it. But I think that order by should first be by inventory_date and then by inventory_id. Is that right?

Comment: @Nancy Then what when there is more then one purchase with different prices in a given date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65032/discussion-between-nancy-and-clodoaldo-neto).

Comment: I have question regarding performence using this method. What if the entries of products grows in this inventory table for each product_id? Any bad effect on db instance memory usage?